# typo3 v.6 fluid template: getting Distribution.png (box with question mark) instead of wanted image

Tags: image, typo3, fluid

I am getting Distribution.png (box with question mark) instead of wanted image while using fluid template, typo3 v6.0.
This is my root template:

```
config.no_cache = 1
config.doctype = html5

page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0

page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    format = html
    file = fileadmin/templates/layouts/main.html
    partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/partials/
    layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/layouts/
    variables {
        content < styles.content.get
        content.select.where = colPos = 0
        content_left < styles.content.get
        content_left.select.where = colPos = 1
        content_right < styles.content.get
        content_right.select.where = colPos = 2
    }
}

page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject {
    key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
    key.override.field = backend_layout

    default = TEXT
    default.value = fileadmin/templates/threeColumn.html
    2 = TEXT
    2.value = fileadmin/templates/threeColumn.html
    3 = TEXT
    3.value = fileadmin/templates/fullSize.html

}
```

In version 4.5 everyting is working ok.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which image do you mean?

Comment: where do you want to get a image? i can't see, where you going to implement an image.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/b608vnpfr/ this image. Instead of images(from backend) I get always that one specific image. Test pictures(of Jesus) in test are displayed correctly.

Comment: This is get on my frontend: http://postimg.org/image/suxlkg9xv/