# TYPO3 distribution.png issue when posting images

Tags: typo3, typoscript

This issue has already been raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724051/typo3-v-6-fluid-template-getting-distribution-png-box-with-question-mark-inst) but without answer. I am not sure it is exactly the same problem.

My website uses TYPO3 6.2. It includes 3 static templates:

- CSS Styled Content
- Bootstrap Package
- Fluid content elements: Twitter Bootstrap

The Typoscript is only a custom CSS that can be removed without change.

The problem is that every image added through the page editor in a typical page content (as "Text and Images" or "Images Only"), the displayed image is always the following:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8382436/3890832/e6d2b1e6-2223-11e4-88d3-f319b692803b.png

With this URL:

```
http://my-site-url.ext/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Resources/Public/Images/Distribution.png
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a [German forum](http://typo3.toaster-schwerin.de/typo3_german/2014_05/msg00344.html), I found the solution.

In the backend, `Installation tool > All configuration> $ TYPO3_CONF_VARS ['FE']`,

set the variable `[FE] [activateContentAdapter]  = 1`.

Then the images were displayed with me immediately.

If someone has a reason for why this issue occured, I will be gratefull.

Comment: You sir, get a beer and a kudo!